# How to mark executed event, columnwise

Tags: excel, vba

I want to mark up or highlight executed even digit out of five even numeric digits (0 2 4 6 8), when 4th digit (senior most) arrives out of five even digit column wise.

Example data:

```
8
2
6
0 (executed)
6
2
4 (executed)
2
0 (executed)
8 (executed)
6 (executed)
6
4 (executed)
2 (executed)
2
6
0 (executed)
2
6
6
2
4 (executed)
0 (executed)
6 (executed)
0
6
0
6
6
0
6
8 (executed)
0
6
6
2 (executed)
4 (executed)
0 (executed)
8 (executed)
```

Executed digits have to be highlighted with bold or with a color.

Comment: We can help you on your code, please add your example after finding it or any code that you tried it.

Comment: Sir i tried using .select in Excel vba Macros and Dim am confused please help, no idea

Comment: I add an answer to give you an idea, but you should add more details and scenario details to your question ;).

Answer (score 0):

I think this code can guide you to your solution:

```
Public Sub HighlightCols()
    ' Declare your variables
    Dim ColumnNo As Long
    Dim RowNo As Long
    Dim digit As Integer

    Dim isHighlighted As Boolean
    Dim uniqueDigits As String
    Dim lastUniqueDigits As String

    ColumnNo = 1

    Do
        RowNo = 1
        uniqueDigits = ""
        lastUniqueDigits = ""

        ' A simple way to find the last row by its value that is empty (or "")
        If (Trim(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, ColumnNo).Value & " ") = "") Then Exit Do

        Do
            ' A simple way to find the last row by its value that is empty (or "")
            If (Trim(ActiveSheet.Cells(RowNo, ColumnNo).Value & " ") = "") Then Exit Do

            ' You have your digit value of your row
            digit = Val(ActiveSheet.Cells(RowNo, ColumnNo).Value)

            ' As default highlight is false
            isHighlighted = False

            If Not (uniqueDigits Like "*" & CStr(digit) & "*") Then
                uniqueDigits = uniqueDigits & CStr(digit)
                If (Len(uniqueDigits) >= 4) Then
                    isHighlighted = True
                    lastUniqueDigits = uniqueDigits2Top(RowNo, ColumnNo)
                    uniqueDigits = ""

                ElseIf Not (Right(lastUniqueDigits, 3) Like "*" & CStr(digit) & "*") And (lastUniqueDigits <> "") Then
                    lastUniqueDigits = uniqueDigits2Top(RowNo, ColumnNo)
                    isHighlighted = True

                End If
            End If

            ' Assign your clue for highlighting
            If (isHighlighted) Then

                ' I set highlighting by a yellow background
                ActiveSheet.Cells(RowNo, ColumnNo).Interior.Color = vbYellow

            Else
                ActiveSheet.Cells(RowNo, ColumnNo).Interior.Color = vbWhite

            End If

            ' Preparing for next row
            RowNo = RowNo + 1

        Loop

        ' Preparing for next column
        ColumnNo = ColumnNo + 1
        RowNo = 1
    Loop    ' Use loop statements instead of goto
End Sub

Private Function uniqueDigits2Top(ByVal curRow As Long, ByVal curCol As Long) As String
    Dim uniqueDigits As String
    uniqueDigits = ""
    uniqueDigits2Top = uniqueDigits
    Do
       If Not (uniqueDigits Like "*" & Trim(ActiveSheet.Cells(curRow, curCol).Value & " ") & "*") Then
           uniqueDigits = uniqueDigits & Trim(Val(ActiveSheet.Cells(curRow, curCol).Value & ""))
           If (Len(uniqueDigits) = 3) Then
               uniqueDigits2Top = uniqueDigits
               Exit Function
           End If
       End If

       curRow = curRow - 1
       If curRow < 1 Then Exit Function

    Loop
End Function
```

Comment: Sir, this code is not working, what i want is in a particular column say in Column A, after arriving three unique digit out of five(0 2 4 6 8 ), the 4th digit which will come should highlight in that particular column  only, example 0 4 2 0 4 8 in this case 8 (pending was 6,8, so 8 came)has to highlight means when senior pending 4th digits comes it should highlight, next pending senior is 2 &6 out of this two when any one comes that should highlight, it has to happen for the whole sheet for all the columns, considering each column data within

Comment: Sir, in short if see from bottom to top in any column after arrival of three unique digit the remaining two is pending or senior, when any out of these two comes that has to be highlighted,

Comment: Sir you are almost there,  in some place it is highlighting properly and in some cases it is not  highlighting  when senior comes(pending), sir please check with this example sir please don't feel bad, 0 2 2 0 2 4 0 6 8 2 2 8 8 6 0 4  in this case when senior comes in one place it is not highlighted, sir for your information when senior comes it has to consider that highlighted digit(yellow) also to find next pending(senior)   in short please see this example 0 2 4 6 0 in this came when 6 comes it will highlighted in yellow, next it has to consider 6(yellow) also to find next senior. pl help

Comment: sir i tried but i was not getting idea sorry please help in this case after seeing i will definitely make improvement

Comment: sir i ask apology am learning please do write code for this, please sir  i am not getting idea how to write for this

Comment: Sir, out of five unique digit (0 2 4 6 8) every time we need to consider after arrival of three unique digit, not four, there remains two unique digit which is senior among the five digit, out of this any one comes know it has to highlight.then considering this highlighted digit we need to look from bottom to top, again there we will get three unique digit, again there it creates new two senior (pending) out of five, after arrival of any digit among these two it has to highlight. like this sir am a rural student poor in english, if you see my 1st example what i want mentioned as executed(yell)

Comment: @SubramanyaNk :p please give example on your main example on your question; that you have (`[8, 2, 6, 0x], [6, 2, 4x, 2, 0x], [8x, 6x, 6, 4x, 2x]`) In that data you have three block of 4 unique digits that after first block `4` digits in second block, and after second block `8` in third block should highlighted, As bottom to top in first block I think `2` in second block should highlighted but it's not highlighted, What's my misunderstanding?

Comment: sir for understanding purpose in my main example you assume it is given only first three data i.e 8 2 6 now pending (Yet to come) is  0 & 4, next came 0, this has to highlight, now including this highlighted 0, if you see from bottom to top required three digit out of five, you will find 2 6 0 so our next pending digit will be 4 & 8 , so next came was 6 it is not our pending, next came 2 this is also not pending , next came was 4 this is pending and has to be highlighted. Now again if you see from bottom you will see 6 2 4 now pending will be 0 & 8, so next came is 2, not pending next came 0

Comment: this 0 has to highlight, again if you see you will find from bottom 4 2 0  now pending will be 6&8 like this

Comment: Sir you are simply superb thanks a lot, sorry i took lot of your valuable time

Comment: @SubramanyaNk When you got your answer, click on tick mark at top left side of the answer and click on above triangle to upvote (that means the answer is useful).

Comment: sir i did but it came as vote up requires 15 reputation